# How to replace everything outside of quote marks? - REGEX Komodo Edit/Notepad++

Tags: php, regex

Could somebody tell me the regular expression for replacing everything outside of quote marks with white space?

Example text :

```
permalink_title='$permalink_title', 
code_size_3='$code_size_3', 
code_size_3='$code_size_3', 
code_size_35='$code_size_35', 
code_size_4='$code_size_4', 
code_size_45='$code_size_45', 
code_size_5='$code_size_5', 
code_size_55='$code_size_55', 
code_size_6='$code_size_6', 
code_size_65='$code_size_65', 
code_size_7='$code_size_7', 
code_size_75='$code_size_75', 
code_size_8='$code_size_8', 
code_size_85='$code_size_85', 
code_size_9='$code_size_9',  
code_size_95='$code_size_95', 
code_size_10='$code_size_10', 
code_size_105='$code_size_105',
```

So the expression would replace everything outside of `'$permalink_title'` with whitespace. Ideally it would go one better and replace everything with whitespace leaving only the PHP variable - `$permalink_title`

*Note - I was going to perform this function with Komodo Edit or Notepad++

Any help would be great.

Comment: `sed -e "s/^.+'//g" -e "s/'.+$//g"`

Comment: @scragar - I've just updated my question. I want to be able to enter this into the Find/Replace interface in Komodo Edit or Notepad++. Thanks

Comment: For notepad++ I know `^.+'(.+)'.+$` replaced with `\1` works.

Comment: @scragar - Sorry I don't follow. Could you please provide me with the specific regex line. Thanks

Comment: Seriously, do exactly as I said. http://i.imgur.com/ntTlgEB.png?1?8195

Comment: @scragar - Alright! Got it now. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54636/discussion-between-aphex22-and-scragar).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this regex :

```
(^[^']+|(?<=')[^']+$)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/qSXwhk9I_XMyWnXH)

Comment: Downvote? I've ticked the answer as accepted and upvoted. Your answer has been very helpful, appreciated.

Comment: @Aphex22 Never said *you* downvoted ;) Glad to help you.